# Getting multiple cookie values for same cookie different paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Working on a local url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/qa/`

Setting cookies using this JS code:

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + newSize + "; " + expires; + "path=/";
}
```

If I call setCookie from /qa/, I can see that the following cookie has been set:

```
Name=font; Value=12px; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/qa
```

If I subsequently call setCookie from a different url (eg /qa/profile), I see that a second cookie has been created as follows:

```
Name=font; Value=12px; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/qa
Name=font; Value=18px; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/qa/profile
```

What I want is for any call to setCoookie to override the previous value of the initial cookie so that there is only ever one cookie with name="font" and that its value always reflects the last set value. I thought that specifying `"path=/";` in my jquery function would do the trick. But it hasn't. What am I doing wrong?